Edge-coloring problem of a regular graph
Let $G$ be a regular graph with a cut vertex. Show that $\chi'(G)=d+1$, where $\chi'(G)$ is the edge-chromatic number of $G$ and $d$ is the degree of vertices.
Vizing's theorem tells that $\Delta(G) \leq \chi'(G) \leq \Delta(G)+1$ for all graphs, where $\Delta(G)$ is the maximum degree. So we are left to prove that $G$ doesn't have a $d$-edge-coloring. It's easy to consider using contradiction, as edges attached to one fixed vertex must be colored by all $d$ colors if such coloring exists.
The problem is "what's next"?

Suppose the claim is false.

Choose a counterexample $G=(V,E)$ for which $n=|V|$ is least. 

Assume $G$ is $d$-regular.

As you noted, from the $d$-regularity of $G$, it follows that $d\le \chi'(G)\le d+1$, and from the assumption that $G$ is a counterexample, it follows that $\chi'(G)=d$.

Let $v$ be a cut vertex of $G$, and let $H$ be the component of $G$ which contains $v$.

It follows that $v$ is also a cut vertex of $H$.

Since $G$ is $d$-regular, it follows that every component of $G$ is $d$-regular, hence $H$ is $d$-regular.

Since $\chi'(G)=d$, it follows that $\chi'(H)\le d$, and since $H$ is $d$-regular, it follows that $\chi'(H)\ge d$, hence $\chi'(H)=d$.

Thus $H$ qualifies as a counterexample to the claim, hence by minimality of $n$, it follows that $G=H$.

Hence $G$ is connected.

Since $v$ is a cut vertex of $G$, there exist vertices $u,w$ of $G$ such that $u,w$ are in different components of $G-v$.

Let $p$ be a path in $G$ from $u$ to $w$.

Necessarily $p$ passes through $v$.

Of the two vertices of $p$ which are adjacent to $v$, let $u'$ be the one which is in the same component of $G-v$ as $u$, and let $w'$ be the one which is in the same component of $G-v$ as $w$.

It follows that there is no path in $G-v$ from $u'$ to $w'$.

Let $G'$ be the graph obtained by removing all edges from $G$ other those whose colors are the same as those of edges $u'v$ or $vw'$.

Then $G'$ is $2$-regular and $\chi'(G')=2$.

Let $C$ be the component of $G'$ containing $v$.

Then $C$ is a cycle and $u',w'$ are vertices of $C$, hence there is a path in $C-v$ from $u'$ to $w'$.

But that path is also a path in $G-v$, contradiction, which thereby proves the claim.
